# How can create fireworks when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've found this anime JS affect where it creates miniature fireworks. Though I cant seem to figure out how to trigger them when a button is clicked. The fireworks only come up when I click anywhere, I want it to pop up when only I click the button.

What I tried:

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(e){
  window.human = true;
  render.play();
  updateCoords(e);
  animateParticules(pointerX, pointerY);
}, false);
```

**With my tried code:**
https://gyazo.com/8b10888f7a4cd3741f8269cbe14d3b2f

**Without my tried code:**
https://gyazo.com/2a17f86c0e23469b40d96fa46e79eec5

https://codepen.io/dogboy602k/pen/qyVrMx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your codepen it appears that you are trying to target your button via an ID attribute that equals "btn" however you only have a class of "btn" assigned. Add in the correct ID, or target your element by it's current class name and you should be all set.